# Suitescript Identify fulfilled items on sales order?

Tags: suitescript, fulfillment

I am trying to identify which line items on a sales order have been fulfilled and which not. I cannot find a field for this on the item record. I need to perform an operation after certain item types have been fulfilled.
Thank you,
James

Answer (score 1):

you can loop the items

```
      for (var i = 0; i < SaleOrder.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'}); i++) {
 var quantityFullfiled=   SaleOrder.getSublistValue( { sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'quantityfulfilled' }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I would have to compare the quantity fulfilled with the order quantity for each item?

Comment: @Jamesckel if you want to know if is 100% fulfilled yes, other field is SaleOrder.getSublistValue( { sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'quantity' } )

Comment: Was able to try this. Unfortunately, the item sublist field "quantityfulfilled" is not available to the script. When I list all the fields present in the NS debugger, it is not among them and the getSublistValue returns undefined. The only two quantity... fields are quantity and quantityavailable.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using a saved search to do the querying where the fulfilled quantity is available. Crazy how NS exposes fields in some places and not in others.